# Insert Space between Shapes and Connectors in Visio

Tags: uml, visio

I'd like to automatically pad my shapes with some space so that connectors (e.g. arrows) do not touch the shape, but instead are a few pixels away.

This can be achieved by moving the shape connector points away from the shape, but this is a manual, time consuming process which needs to be done per shape which I would like to avoid.

How can I automatically insert a fixed amount of space between connectors and shapes?

Comment: What's your question? It's not terribly clear...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with a Custom Line End.

1. If the Drawing Explorer Window is not shown then View Menu > Drawing Explorer Window.
2. In the Drawing Explorer Window right click on the Line Ends folder.
3. Click New Pattern.
4. Give the Line End a name and select Scaled. Click OK.
5. Right click on the new Line End.
6. Click on Edit Pattern Shape.
7. Draw a small line end e.g. an arrow about 0.125 in square or 3 mm square. The arrow should point to the right.
8. If there line end you created is made of more than one shape group it, e.g. Ctrl+A then Ctrl+G.
9. Zoom in closely to the shape.
10. Make sure the Pointer Tool is selected in the Standard Toolbar.
11. Select the shape.
12. Mouse over the Shape Rotation Handle e.g. the lollypop.
13. A new handle should appear with the tooltip Center of Rotation.
14. Move this handle outside the shape to the right. How far you move will control the offset of your line from the shapes. See image: [image]
15. Close the Pattern Shape window.
16. Click Yes to save the pattern.
17. Select all the lines you want to use the new Line Pattern with.
18. Format Menu > Line
19. Change the Line ends: Begin and Line ends: End to the name of your new Line End. The name will be at the bottom of the list.

The lines begin and ends should now appear offset from the shapes they are connected to.

These instructions are for versions of Visio prior to Visio 2010. In Visio 2010 the menu items described are replace with buttons in the ribbon.